# Having two preferred citations when implementing a CITATION.cff to a project

Tags: github, pyomo, citations

I want to contribute to making citation easier by uploading CITATION.cff files to the packages I have used in a project. One such package, Pyomo, has specified two sources to which to refer if you used their work. CITATIONS.cff have a "preferred citation" category which fits this quite well but I am not sure how to include two sources or if that is at all possible. I have tried simply appending the second source but it seems to override certain fields rather than citing two sources (the latest year and DOI are applied for example). This is how far I have gotten:

```
cff-version: 1.2.0
title: Pyomo
message: >-
  If you use Pyomo in your research, please cite the
  Pyomo book and the Pyomo paper.
type: software
authors:
  - given-names: Michael
    family-names: Bynum
  - given-names: Gabriel
    family-names: Hackebeil
  - given-names: William
    family-names: Hart
  - given-names: Carl
    family-names: Laird
identifiers:
  - type: doi
    value: 10.1007/978-3-319-58821-6
    description: Pyomo — Optimization Modeling in Python
  - type: doi
    value: 10.1007/s12532-011-0026-8
    description: >-
      "Pyomo: modeling and solving mathematical
      programs in Python"
repository-code: 'https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo'
url: 'http://www.pyomo.org/'
preferred-citation:
  type: article
  authors:
  - given-names: Michael
    family-names: Bynum
  - given-names: Gabriel
    family-names: Hackebeil
  - given-names: William
    family-names: Hart
  - given-names: Carl
    family-names: Laird
  doi: "10.1007/s12532-011-0026-8"
  journal: "Mathematical Programming Computation"
  month: 9
  start: 219 # First page number
  end: 260 # Last page number
  title: "Pyomo: modeling and solving mathematical programs in Python"
  issue: 3
  volume: 3
  year: 2011
```

Is it possible to include another preferred citation? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub issue discussion might be helpful: https://github.com/citation-file-format/citation-file-format/issues/339

The intent behind the citations.cff file is to cite the software and hence, there can only be one citation (by design). The preferred citation is intended as an override so that the user can customise the citation.